# AWS Blue-Green deployment. What happens with new data (database) from production while deployment proceeds?

Tags: amazon-web-services, blue-green-deployment

I'm trying to fully understand what happens with new data (new users registered for example) on production, while I'm deploying new features. When I push new code to the repo, the blue-green deployment script creates a new clone of the production, pulls new code from the repo. Then I need some time to test if everything is working as expected. If all looks fine I finish the deployment and the new instance will be replaced with production.
The question is what happens with the data (new users, content, etc.) that was added on production, while I'm testing? This data will be transfer/cloned to a new instance? If yes - how?

Comment: This gets even harder if you plan to slowly increase traffic to your new environment (canary style) rather than simply switch over completely.

Comment: it's something basic I think but can't find simple instructions/explanations.

Comment: It's not simple. It's a hard problem made worse if you're not using an event driven architecture.